# Parse multi level json data with php

Tags: php, json

```
    {
    "books": [
    {
      "id": 2331,
      "image": "http://lol.org/flower.png",
      "images": [
                 {
                  "256x144": "http://lol.org/bee.png",
                  "650x320": "http://lol.org/fly.png"
                  }
                 ],

....
```

I have json data like above but my problem is how to get out 650x320 data.

```
$data = json_decode($jsondata,true);
$gg = sizeof($data['books']);
for($x=0;$x<$gg;$x++){
```

Codes below works fine

```
  $image = $data['books'][$x]['image'];
```

but how to fetch images on a second json level? I have tried code below with no luck.

```
  $image = ($data->{'books'}->{'images'}->{'320x180'});

  $image = $data['books']['images'][$x]['320x180'];
```

Comment: Do a `print_r` of `$data` to see PHP's data structure it got out of the JSON.

Comment: $data['books'][0]['images'][0]["320x180"];

Comment: $image = $data['books'][$x]['images'][0]["320x180"];

yeah, this solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'books'` is an Array of objects, you will need to select an object using a numeric index.

```
$image = $data['books'][$insertIndexHere]['images'][$insertIndexHere]['320x180'];
```

Essentially you have missed the `[$x]` between `'books'` and `'images'` from your first code which works.

You will probably want a loop which iterates through each book and then a second nested loop which iterates through the images in each book.

For example:

```
$gg = sizeof($data['books']);
for($x=0;$x<$gg;$x++) {
   $images = data['books'][$x]['images'];
   $sizeOfImages = sizeof($images);
   for($j = 0; $j < $sizeOfImages; $j++) {
      // access $images[$j]['320x180']
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function getImageLinksFor($json, $dimension='650x320') {
    $links      =   array();
    $objJson    = json_decode($json);

    // GET THE MAIN BOOKS OBJECT...
    $books = $objJson->books;

    // LOOP THROUGH THE $books OBJECT AND PERFORM YOUR SEARCH FOR IMAGES
    foreach ($books as $obj) {
        // SINGLE OUT THE IMAGES OBJECT
        $images = $obj->images;
        // SINCE IT IS ALSO AN ARRAY, SIMPLY LOOP THROUGH IT AND FETCH THE DESIRED DIMENSION.
        foreach ($images as $key => $objImgData) {
            if(property_exists($objImgData, $dimension)){
                $links[] = $objImgData->$dimension;
            }
        }
    }
    if(count($links) == 1){
        return implode("", $links);
    }
    return $links;
}

var_dump(getImageLinksFor($json, '650x320'));
```